# Как реализовать тип в одной библиотеки в другой на c#?

Tags: c#

В процессе чтения clr via c# я узнал, что один тип библиотеки может быть реализован в другой. Например: тип System.IO.FileSystemWatcher реализован в System.dll. Вопрос: Как я могу повторить данный трюк?